# Swiftui - Days' name is missing if you show and hide DatePicker

Tags: swiftui, ios15

I have a `GraphicalDatePickerStyle` `DatePicker` that is hidden by default. When you click a button, it is shown.

It used to work on **iOS14**. But on **iOS15**, days' name is missing.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isDatePickerVisible: Bool = false
    @State var selectedDate = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                isDatePickerVisible.toggle()
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Show")
            })
            
            
            if isDatePickerVisible {
                DatePicker("Enter your birthday",
                           selection: $selectedDate,
                           displayedComponents: .date)
                               .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
            }
        }
     
    }
}
```

#### Result

This is how it looks like when the `DatePicker` is toggled. You see name of the days are not shown.

[image]

---

This is how it looks like by default if you don't hide it.[image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have found a bona fide bug. I can confirm this behavior,  as well as the same behavior with a `DisclosureGroup()`. I did notice that as soon as you select another date, the days of the week appear. They just don't appear from the start. When you file your radar, please post the reference here so everyone can refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

definitely a bug. You can partially get around it by using this:

```
if isDatePickerVisible {
    DatePicker("Enter your birthday", selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: .date)
        .frame(width: 333)   // <--- here
        .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
}
```

Although when I use 444 on macos, it's back to the bug. Note you can also wrap the `DatePicker` in a `Form {DatePicker(...)}` to fix the bug, and it looks quite nice.

Comment: With Form it works. But, the From has `insetGrouped` style, and it seems that it can't be changed.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be an Apple and SwiftUI Bug.

As @workingdog said

> you can get around this by wrapping the DatePicker with a `Form`

or you can use a `List` and setting a Frame on the wrapper. Using a list should affect your UI too much.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            isDatePickerVisible.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Text("Show")
        })
        List {
            if isDatePickerVisible {
                DatePicker("Enter your birthday",
                           selection: $selectedDate,
                           displayedComponents: .date)
                    .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 300)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you show the DatePicker, reset the selection after a few seconds / milliseconds.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
     selection = selection
}
```

```
@State private var selection = Date()

var body: some View {
    DatePicker(
        "Start Date",
        selection: $selection,
        displayedComponents: [.date]
    )
}
```